# Add objects to an empty list

Tags: c#

I'm new to C#, so this question might be an easy one. However I did not find any solution yet.

**Description of the problem:**

I want to create and empty array [4] of lists [length not know]. Later on I will read out four different channels and fill the list with objects created beforehand.

**What I did so far**

```
class objChannel 
{
    private int channel;
    public objChannel(int inputChannel)
    {
        channel = inputChannel;
    }

    public int Channel {get {return channel;}}
}

List<objChannel>[] listChannel = new List<objChannel>[4];

listChannel[1].Add(objChannel(1));
```

This does not work because of an **null** error.

Right now I have a work around like this:

```
List<objChannel>[] listChannel = {new List<objChannel> { new objChannel(1) },
                                  new List<objChannel> { new objChannel(2) },
                                  new List<objChannel> { new objChannel(3) },
                                  new List<objChannel> { new objChannel(4) }};
```

However, this will give me non-empty list.

Comment: First you have to instantiate `listChannel[1]` and then you can call the instance method `Add`.

Comment: You want a _single_ container of `objChannel` or you want a _container of containers_ of `objChannel`??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you initialize your array of lists, you need to create empty lists as well
like:

```
List<objChannel>[] listChannel = {new List<objChannel>(), new List<objChannel>(), new List<objChannel> (), new List<objChannel> ()};
```

or

```
for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
{
    listChannel[i] = new List<objChannel>();
}
```

Comment: Is there an option to do that with even less code? I have to do a similar things which has 17 objChannels. I would like to avoid to write `new List<objChannel>()` so often.

Comment: yes, after creating the listChannel array, use a for loop to create new List<objChannel> objects, see updated answer

Comment: Thanks. I thought there was some secret code I just don't know yet. Seems to be that I just have to do it the `for loop` or `while` way.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your first code is failing is because you have to instantiate the `listChannel[1]` and then you can only call the instance method like:

```
listChannel[1] = new List<objChannel>();
listChannel[1].Add(new objChannel(1));
```

The other point to note is that the array index starts with `0` and not `1`. *(Although not sure if that use in the question was intentional)*.

Comment: Thanks @Habib for the fast reply. That works. Now I have the following `List<objChannel>[] listChannel = new List<objChannel>[4];             listChannel[0] = new List<objChannel>();
            listChannel[1] = new List<objChannel>();
            listChannel[2] = new List<objChannel>();
            listChannel[3] = new List<objChannel>();`